# Which assertions are retained with wholemodule optimization mode?

Tags: swift, compiler-optimization, assertions, compiler-options

All explanations of Swift assertions I can find explain that `assert*` gets thrown out with `-O` but `precondition*` are kept unless `-Ounchecked` is set.

However, we now have [whole-module optimization](https://swift.org/blog/whole-module-optimizations/) `-wmo` as new default for release builds.

Are `precondition*` assertions retained when whole-module optimization is enabled?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1541112-assert and https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1540960-precondition list exactly when the condition is checked or not. I don't think that whole-module optimization makes a difference, but you can easily test it yourself  by adding a failing condition and run the program.

Comment: I don't know about AppCode, but in the Xcode build settings you have "-O -whole-module-optimization". So these are different options, and I would assume that the documentation of assert/precondition is still correct.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, the setting in AppCode confused me. [FWIW](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-14836).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this small program:

```
func f(_ i: Int) -> Int {
    assert(i > 0, "needed positive number")
    return i
}

print(f(0))
```

Compiling it with `xcrun swiftc [opt]` and running the result gives:

- `-Onone`: assertion error
- `-Onone -wmo`: assertion error
- `-O`: prints 0
- `-O -wmo`: prints 0

And in comparison:

```
func f(_ i: Int) -> Int {
    precondition(i > 0, "needed positive number")
    return i
}

print(f(0))
```

- `-Onone`: precondition error
- `-Onone -wmo`: precondition error
- `-O`: Illegal instruction: 4
- `-O -wmo`: Illegal instruction: 4

I can't quite explain the last two results, but it seems clear that whole-module optimization does not influence how assertions are handled; only the optimization level matters.

---

This is on

```
Apple Swift version 3.0.1 (swiftlang-800.0.58.6 clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

Comment: I think the relevant bits from the `precondition` documentation that explain the last two results you got are "*In playgrounds and -Onone builds [...]: If condition evaluates to false, stop program execution **in a debuggable state after printing message**.*" and "*In -O builds [...]: If condition evaluates to false, **stop program execution.***". Running your second example in Xcode in a -O build shows that it just gives an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION rather than printing any kind of error message. The only promise Swift gives you in a -O build is that a failed precondition will stop the program.

Comment: May also be worth noting down the results for `-Ounchecked` (`-wmo`) – whole module optimization doesn't appear to affect the results in that case either.

Comment: @Hamish True -- the behaviour fulfills this specification. I guess they keep the check but optimize away the message? I for one would prefer the message in these cases, otherwise there is very limited use for `precondition` over `assert`.